# Обособление приложений

Tags: приложение

Правильно ли я понимаю, что приложение распространенное и заканчивается вместе с точкой и запятая в скобках не нужна?

В это время к нам присоединился Кшиштоф, тренер и практик в области бережливого производства, философии Kaizen и всеобщего управления качеством (,) с более чем девятилетним опытом в проектировании и конвейерах и логистических системах.

Comment: Аленка, дайте оригинальную (немецкую?) фразу, это проще перевести заново, чем гадать. Тут, видимо наложились ляпы компьютерного перевода на косноязычие автора. Так оставлять нельзя в любом случае, тут не в запятой дело, а в полном отсутствии связанной речи.

Comment: Оригинала у меня, к сожалению, нет, но это, видимо, перевод с  польского...

Comment: Что-то очень сырой для польского-то. Польский интуитивно русскому человеку понятен, там грамматика-то общеславянская, только слова переводить.  Попробуйте все-таки спросить у автора оригинал, а то крайне двусмысленная фраза получается. Я не корректор ни разу, но не рискнул бы в тираж такое...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая точно нужна. Качество с более чем девятилетним опытом?! Хотя бы из-за этого.

Окончание фразы более чем непонятно. ))

Comment: Спасибо. Может быть "...и работе с конвейерами и логистическими системами"?

Comment: Не качество с опытом, а управление. Как вариант, разумеется, против Кшиштофа с опытом.

Answer (score 0):

Тут зависит от того, к чему относится девятилетний опыт. Если к самому этому деятелю, то да, запятая нужна, а если к управлению, то зачем она там? Фраза настолько корявая, что и понять нельзя.

А вообще надо править, если допускается.

***В это время к нам присоединился Кшиштоф, тренер и практик в области бережливого производства, философии Kaizen и всеобщего управления качеством, имеющий более чем девятилетний опыт проектирования и работы с конвейерами и логистическими системами.***

(это только вариант понимания, что там на самом деле автор хотел сказать, не берусь судить. Откуда вы этих "чертей нерусских" вообще берете? Или это результат машинного перевода?)

В любом случае за *"с более чем десятилетним"* убивать надо. ***"Более чем с десятилетним"*** - только так.

Comment: Спасибо, буду в дальнейшем учитывать.

Comment: >> *В любом случае за "с более чем десятилетним" убивать надо. "Более чем с десятилетним" - только так.*   В корне не согласен. Я бы сказал, что только первый вариант. Гугл за меня ))

Comment: Niemand, когда-то я вас уважал за аргументированность. Увы, те времена, видимо прошли. Видимо, вам гугл ближе.